# Which popular rapid web development frameworks follow the "Rails paradigm"?

Tags: php, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, web-frameworks

I'm trying to compile a list of notable web frameworks in wide use that follow the "Rails paradigm", which in the context of this question is defined as web frameworks following these key principles:

- Convention over Configuration (CoC)
- Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)
- Sensible defaults
- Easy scaffolding: automatic generation of CRUD interfaces

This is the list so far:

- Ruby on Rails (Ruby), released in 2004, >6500 questions on SO tagged "ruby-on-rails"
- Django (Python), released in 2005, >3400 questions on SO tagged "django"
- Grails (Groovy), released in 2006, >500 questions on SO tagged "grails"

The nuber of questions tagged on SO is taken as a proxy for the popularity of the web framework.

Question:

- **Which other notable web frameworks currently in wide use should fit in this list?**

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting proxy. Wouldn't the number of questions be more directly related to the number of problems in a framework instead of its popularity? php and asp.net have much larger numbers :)

Comment: Stephan: It's not a perfect proxy, but it is the best proxy around. Please feel free to suggest an alternative measure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
I'm sure cake follows at least two of those principles:

- Easy scaffolding ('Baking' something)
- CoC (stated on the main page)

As for the other two, I can't say for sure. Hopefully someone else can give a definitive answer on that.

Answer (score 2):

LIFT, http://liftweb.net/, which was written in Scala, for Scala.

**UPDATE:**

From the website:

Lift borrows from the best of existing frameworks, providing

```
* Seaside's highly granular sessions and security
* Rails fast flash-to-bang
* Django's "more than just CRUD is included"
* Wicket's designer-friendly templating style
```

Comment: LIFT is certainly inspired by Rails/Django. Is it currently in wide use?

Comment: It is still new, but as people develop more with Scala then it will gain a wider audience.  I was thinking about that after I posted, that this will exclude any new frameworks for relatively new languages.  I don't know how wide of use it is, as I have never checked, I am hoping to release my first LIFT website app this year. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and your clarification. LIFT certainly looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think ASP.NET MVC fits the list. Technically the scaffolding bit is/can be done by Visual Studio, rather than the framework itself, but some of the stated design philosophies (sorry, can't find the links at the time of writing) match you list of CoC, DRY, etc.

**Update**

From [ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part7.htm) *(Guthrie, Hanselmann, Haack, Conery)*:

> One of the design philosophies ASP.NET MVC embraces is the "Do Not Repeat Yourself" principle (commonly referred to as "DRY").  A DRY design helps eliminate the duplication of code and logic, which ultimately makes applications faster to build and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

I think [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) is a good option too, The latest release puts it closer to Rails. It is also rumored to be much faster than cakephp. If you are thinking in terms of performance and PHP frameworks then surely have a look at it. Zend and CodeIgniter are nice robust frameworks, but from my experience are not rails-like.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, [Seaside](http://www.seaside.st) is the only one really doing DRY, but the number of posts on SO is not that large.